# Swift - Static UITableView growing with UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a static UITableView and one of my rows have a UITextView inside of it with autolayout pinned top to bottom left to right as 0.

I want the UITableView's contentView to resize depending on the content of the UITextView however I'm having difficulties working around this. I've scrapped the code I originally used as it wasn't working at all. Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If the content of the textview is static.** 
Set SrollingEnabled to false in UITextView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**If the content of the textview is dynamic.**

Do the same thing as static and set the delegate for UITextView to self. Then in UITextview delegate.

```
   func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

This will definitely work.

Comment: Great that works. Only problem is that it doesn't update automatically whilst I type, the content of the UITextView isn't static and changes.

Comment: Please tell me if you got it not.

Comment: Haha I actually done that before you edited your answer, nevertheless it's correct thank you.